# how to handle NumberFormatException in more specific way?

Tags: java, exception, validation, numberformatexception

I want to handle NumberFormatException in more specific way.
This exception occurs, when it tries assign anything but an integer, when the following is entered:

1. string
2. character
3. empty input
4. double number

Depending on what was entered I want to display a proper message, like

> you've entered string, please enter an integer

or

> value can't be null, please enter an integer value

The code below catches `NumberFormatException` in general way.

I wonder is there a way to include more catch clauses.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TestException {

        static int input;
        static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer number: ");

            try {
                input = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
                System.out.println("You've entered number: " + input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("You've entered non-integer number");
                System.out.println("This caused " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just display in similar lines "You have entered either blank or non-numeric value. Please try again" ?? it is better right?

Comment: You can analyze the given input in the catch clause, obviously there is no built-in logic to determine various arbitrary reasons why the string was invalid as a number

Comment: Also Terminate process with error code. System.exit(1);

Comment: It could be overkill but you can use regex to see the pattern for whether they are digits or alphabets or combination of both.

Answer (score 5):

First take the input from the user and after that try to convert it to integer.

```
    static int input;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number: ");

        String inputString = scan.next();

        try {
            input = Integer.parseInt();
            System.out.println("You've entered number: " + input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if(inputString.equals("") || inputString == null) {
                System.out.println("empty input"); 
            } else if(inputString.length == 1) {
                System.out.println("char input");
            } else {
                System.out.println("string input");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to use `if-else` construct to specify your scenerios within `catch` block.

See the code below:

```
String inString = null;
try 
{
    iString = scan.next().trim();
    input = Integer.parseInt(inString);
    System.out.println("You've entered number: " + input);
} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
    if(inString.equals("")
    {
        System.out.println("You've entered empty string.");
    }
    else if(inString.length() == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("You've entered a single char");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You've entered non-intereger number");
    }
    System.out.println("This caused " + e);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. When I just hit Enter, this is an empty string, but your code doesn't check for the 1st condition, so it goes to the last "else" condition

Answer (score 1):

You could do some more tests on the input if parsing the input as an integer value caused an exception, something like this:

```
String scanned = null
try {
   scanned = scan.next();
   input = Integer.parseInt(scanned);
   System.out.println("You've entered number: " + input);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   if (scanned == null || scanned.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("You didn't enter any value");
   } else if (scanned.length() == 1)
      System.out.println("You entered a single char which is not a number");
   }
   // and more tests, you can even try to parse as Double
}
```

Comment: scanned.size() --> scanned.length()

Answer (score 0):

```
String aString = null;
    aString = scan.next().trim();   
    System.out.println("You've entered number: " + aString);
    if("".equals(aString.trim())){
       System.out.println("You have entered an Empty String");
     }else if(!isNumber(aString) && aString.length()==1){
       System.out.println("You have entered a Character");
     }else if(!isNumber(aString) && aString.length()>1){
       System.out.println("You have entered a String");
     }else if(isNumber(aString)){
       int input = Integer.parseInt(aString.replaceAll(",",""));
       System.out.println("You have entered a correct Number"+input); 
     }

   private boolean isNumber(String s){
        return s.matches("[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?");
    }
```

Comment: This will throw a `NumberFormatException` without catching it and thus end the program (and the number regex isn't right, either).

Comment: No, it won't because you're not converting the input to `int` anymore, which is what OP wants to do. And the regex is still wrong.

Comment: The regx already works for me. Just check the regx if you enter 1,000 also it works and gives you correct o/p.

Comment: Now I see, the regex works for you, because you replace all the commas. But then your regex could be written much easier like `\\d[\\d,]*`. Now all you need to fix is the scope of the varible `input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int isInt(){
        boolean ok=false;
        int b=1;
        do{
            String next = sc.next();
            int a=b;
            try{
             a = Integer.parseInt(next);        
            }catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println("Invalid Option...");
                continue;
            }


            if(a==1){b=a;ok=true;}
            else if(a==2){b=a;ok=true;}
            else if(a==3){b=a;ok=true;}

        }while(!ok);
    return b;
}
```