# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"

Tags: java

I search a lot for solve this error but no solution seems to be appropriate.

I'm using **Swing** to build a simple interface. This interface has a **JTextField** where user has to write a number, this number **must be positive** to let the save button to be enabled.

I want that if the user enters a number>=1, the save button will be enabled and if the user enters a negative number continue to be disabled.

I wrote a **test** where the user try to enter a negative number:

```
    @Test
    public void testWhenQuantityTextBoxIsNegativeNumberThenSaveButtonShouldBeDisabled() {
        window.textBox("quantityTextBox").enterText("-5");
        window.button(JButtonMatcher.withText("Save")).requireDisabled();
    }
```

And this is the **code of JTextField** quantityTextBox:

```
textQuantity = new JTextField();
        KeyAdapter btnSaveEnabler = new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                btnSave.setEnabled(!(Integer.parseInt(textQuantity.getText()) < 1));
        }
};
textQuantity.addKeyListener(btnSaveEnabler);
textQuantity.setEnabled(true);
textQuantity.setName("quantityTextBox");
```

The problem is that when I try to to convert a negative number represented as a string ("-5") into an integer type I have this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
>   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

The problem seems to be the "-" sign before number 5.

I undertand that the problem is given by  `Integer.parseInt` but I don't know how to solve it.

I try to change `Integer.parseInt` with `Double.parseDouble` but nothing changed.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Tom, now I know that:

> The problem is not the -5, the problem is that you check the number on each key press, so it tries to check the - without any number.

So I try to changed with `keyReleased()` with `keyPressed()` but now I have:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

and:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"

So I try with `keyTyped()` but still have the same error.

I really don't know how to solve it.

If something is not clear please ask me and sorry for my english.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: this is neither swing nor JTextField related. What your error message tells you, is that you are trying to parse "-" to a numerical value, but "-" is not a numerical value.

Comment: The problem is not the `-5`, the problem is that you check the number on each key press, so it tries to check the `-` without any number. The exception message tells you that already.

Comment: yes, I already knew, how you could see I write: "I undertand that the problem is given by Integer.parseInt but I don't know how to solve it.".

Comment: @Tom thanks I haven't seen it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle NumberFormatException in more specific way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252427/how-to-handle-numberformatexception-in-more-specific-way)

Comment: And this one: [What is the proper way to handle a NumberFormatException when it is expected?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4410107) ... they both might help you here

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks for your help. This links help to handle the NumberFormatException, you suggest it because there is no way to read the string "-5", isn't it?

Comment: Like I already said, your problem is not "-5", your problem is that you read the stuff too early so the user doesn't even have the change to type "5" when you already read "-" and "-" alone is no number. Also, you want to handle non-integer input values, so you need to handle these NumberFormatExceptions anyway. Both links tell you how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `try` statement to catch any `NumberFormatException`:

```
KeyAdapter btnSaveEnabler = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            try {
                btnSave.setEnabled(!(Integer.parseInt(textQuantity.getText()) < 1));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                btnSave.setEnabled(false);
            }
    }
};
```

This would be a good idea *even if you weren't already expecting a `NumberFormatException`* when the user inputs the initial `-` of a negative number.  Because a `JTextField` places no restrictions on what the user can type, you can never be absolutely certain that `textQuantity.getText()` will return a value that `Integer.parseInt()` can parse without throwing a `NumberFormatException`.  So better to be prepared than be surprised, especially because "surprised" means an uncaught exception and thus a sudden and grim death for your program.